# Trying to format timer like 5:00 instead of 500

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to make a timer and it works fine really.

How am I supposed to put a : between the numbers,  is their an easy way to do it?

It currently displays like this `500` and counts down and works fine. I want it to display like this `5:00` is there any easy way just to put that one character quickly in?

I just want it to countdown from five minutes to zero.

Or would I have to format the timer differently to be able to do that.

```js
var timer;

var time = 500;

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  time--;

  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');

  if (time === 499) {
    time = 459;
  } else if (time === 399) {
    time = 359;
  } else if (time === 299) {
    time = 259;
  } else if (time === 199) {
    time = 159;
  } else if (time === 99) {
    time = 59;
  }


  if (time > 0) {
    timeText.innerHTML = time;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeText.innerHTML = 'end';
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', time);
  window.open('02page2.html', "_self");
}

function loadTimer() {
  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('timerem') === null) {
    timeText.innerHTML = 'ERROR';
  } else {
    time = sessionStorage.getItem('timerem');
    timeText.innerHTML = time;
    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }
}

startTimer()
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: `seconds / 60 = mins` `seconds % 60 = remaining seconds` calculate them both and display them on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
const formatTime = num => (num/100).toFixed(2).replace(".",":");
```

```js
const formatTime = num => (num/100).toFixed(2).replace(".",":");


var timer;

var time = 500;

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  time--;

  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');

  if (time === 499) {
    time = 459;
  } else if (time === 399) {
    time = 359;
  } else if (time === 299) {
    time = 259;
  } else if (time === 199) {
    time = 159;
  } else if (time === 99) {
    time = 59;
  }


  if (time > 0) {
    timeText.innerHTML = formatTime(time);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeText.innerHTML = 'end';
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', time);
  window.open('02page2.html', "_self");
}

function loadTimer() {
  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('timerem') === null) {
    timeText.innerHTML = 'ERROR';
  } else {
    time = sessionStorage.getItem('timerem');
    timeText.innerHTML = formatTime(time)
    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }
}

startTimer()
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Shorter version of your code without the page change and session storage - the session storage does not run in a stack snippet.

This is using actual time

```js
const timeText = document.getElementById('timer');
let timer;
let time = 5*60*1000; // 5 minutes in millisecs

function startTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer); // in case of restart
  timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  time-=1000;

  const mmss = new Date(time).toISOString().substr(14, 5)

  if (time > 0) {
    timeText.textContent = mmss
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeText.innerHTML = 'end';
  }
}
startTimer()
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and thank you for the response but what does this command do. Sorry if you have the time could you just give me a basic explanation of how this works in like a couple of lines if you could just that would be really helpful.                        
 The comment is  ---     const formatTime = num => (num/100).toFixed(2).replace(".",":");

Comment: I take a number, divide it by 100, then make sure it has two decimals and replace the decimal point with a colon

Comment: But this is more elegant: `const mmss = new Date(time).toISOString().substr(14, 5)` make a date, take the string and chop off the start to keep the mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var timer;

var time = 500;

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  time--;

  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');


  if (time > 0) {
    timeText.innerHTML = (time/100).toFixed(2).replace(".",":");
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeText.innerHTML = 'end';
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timerem', time);
  window.open('02page2.html', "_self");
}

function loadTimer() {
  var timeText = document.getElementById('timer');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('timerem') === null) {
    timeText.innerHTML = 'ERROR';
  } else {
    time = sessionStorage.getItem('timerem');
    timeText.innerHTML = (time/100).toFixed(2).replace(".",":");
    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }
}

startTimer()


</script>
</head>
<body>

<span id="timer"></span>

</body>
</html>
```